# Send reply which is not visible to others in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

**So i want something like this**
[image]

**But when i try to do  `ctx.reply("replied")` it is seen by everyone how to do it like the above image?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send ephemeral messages only as response to interaction (slash command or component like button or select). If you want to create a slash commands you need to use **discord.py** forks or extension for it:

- [enhanced d.py](https://github.com/iDevision/enhanced-discord.py)
- [nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord)
- [discord-interactions](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [pycord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord)

Or new APIs for python:

- [hikari](https://github.com/hikari-py/hikari)
- [dis-snek](https://github.com/Discord-Snake-Pit/Dis-Snek) (still in development)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pycord

so you can easily create slash command and ephemeral

```
pip install pycord
```

---

```
pip uninstall discord.py
```

---

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.slash_command()
async def mycommand(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("hello i'm an hidded message",ephemeral=True)

bot.run("your bot token")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).